# scraping sports table from oddsportal

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping

I try to scrape this webpage https://www.oddsportal.com/moving-margins
But the code sometime work, and sometimes don't, and even if work don't scrape all the data I need per match.

```
u = 'https://www.oddsportal.com/moving-margins/'
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=r"C:\chromedriver.exe")
driver.maximize_window()
driver.get(u)
#Use Explicit time wait for fast execution
WebDriverWait(driver, 30).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "#moving_margins_content_overall")))
driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight)")
table_data =  driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//div[@id='moving_margins_content_overall']//tr[@class='odd' or @class='dark']")
table =[]
# Creating a list of lists, where each list consist all data in each row either with class dark or odd

for data in table_data:
    row = []
    dark_row = data.find_elements_by_xpath((".//th//a"))
    for col in dark_row:
        row.append(col.text.replace("\n"," "))
    odd_row = data.find_elements_by_xpath((".//following-sibling::tr[@class='odd']//td"))
    for col in odd_row:
        row.append(col.text.replace("\n", " "))
    table.append(row)
```

My goal is to store data into csv file with those columns:

```
sport    country    competiton    handicap    match_date  match                  hdp_open  hdp_close  bookmaker
Tennis   Czech      Ostrava..     AH 0 Games  Today12:00  Karatsev A. - Otte O.  0.5       -1.5      Nordicbet
```

Comment: "the code sometime work, and sometimes don't" doesn't explain what the problem is, could you be more precise? Do you have any error? What does it mean that it doesn't work.

Comment: sometimes return an error: selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":".//following-sibling::tr//th[@class='first2']"}

Comment: try copying the full Xpath and runnning the Code.

Comment: even if I change the xpath, the data scraped is not all the data present on the table

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the problem in you code is that the page has, in some cases, a single "dark" row for many "odds" rows. So when you loop the elements, you create a single record for a table that actually has more records.

This code should fit you needs, but keep in mind that it's not optimal since doesn't take care of possible exceptions, but it's a starting point:

```py
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait
import selenium.webdriver.support.expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

u = 'https://www.oddsportal.com/moving-margins/'
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=r"chromedriver.exe")
driver.maximize_window()
driver.get(u)
#Use Explicit time wait for fast execution
WebDriverWait(driver, 30).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "#moving_margins_content_overall")))
driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight)")
tables =  driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//div[@id='moving_margins_content_overall']//table")
tableData =[]

for table in tables:
    trDark = table.find_element_by_xpath('.//tr[@class="dark"]')
    trOdds = table.find_elements_by_xpath('.//tr[@class="odd"]')

    row = [trDark.text.strip().replace("\n", " ")]
    for odd in trOdds:
        tds = [
            td.text.strip().replace("\n", " ") 
            for td in odd.find_elements_by_xpath('.//td')
        ]
        row = row + tds
    tableData.append(row)

print(tableData)
```